# My migration file raising an error while running "php artisan migrate"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, php-7.2

I am getting the error as

> "Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'key' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `admin_settings` where `key` != null limit 1)"

because of the function in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
 public function boot()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('admin_settings')) {
            $google_analytics_details = AdminSetting::where('key','!=','null')->first();

        }else {
            $google_analytics_details = '';
        }        
        View::share('google_analytics_details', $google_analytics_details);
    }
```

when i comment the **code of the boot function** then it migrates successfully.

I am looking an alternative for this view sharing.
can anyone help me??

My migration file content:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class UpdateAdminSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
         Schema::table('admin_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('google_analytics_code');
        });

        Schema::table('admin_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->longText('key')->nullable()->after('id');
            $table->longText('value')->nullable()->after('key');

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
         Schema::table('admin_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {

        });


    }
}
```

Comment: did you including 'Use App/AdminSetting' on header?

Comment: is there is a key field ?

Comment: Do you have that column in the table? Can you post your migration? Maybe use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers)?

Comment: What is your table structure? Did you spell check the column's name? (Key vs key etc)

Comment: no @kerbh0lz , I don't have that column thats why i was running migration, to make that column.

Comment: Try defining the up() function and use the following:
` public function up()
{
    Schema::table('admin_settings', function($table) {
        $table->integer('key');
    });
} `

Comment: So your table exists but that column doesn't? You can use `if (Schema::hasColumn('admin_settings', 'key')) { // }` to check for the existance of that column

Comment: Thanks @kerbh0lz it works after checking that column exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  [view composers doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers)

if you want to share variable to one view (that may be loaded or extended to other views e.g. `layout.app`) you can specify the view name as example below

simple example:

```
View::composer('view-name', function ($view) {
             $view->with('key', 'value');
        });
```

or if you need it in all of your views you can use `*` as view name like this

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
             $view->with('key', 'value');
        });
```

### Another way to solve your problem

your issue with migration can also be solved with a condition before sharing the view

```
 public function boot()
    {
        if ( !app()->runningInConsole() ){
             // your code here
        }
    }
```